# How to open file in Django and save this in ImageField?

Tags: django

How to open file in Django and save this in ImageField (`thumb`)?

```
...
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(www)
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png') #I need to save this file in field `thumb`
browser.quit()


Website.objects.create(name=fullname, thumb=HERE_MY_SCREENSHOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if you haven't created a model.
Then copy your image file to the upload path (assumed = 'path/' in following snippet).

```
  class Layout(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField('img', upload_to='path/')
```

Second, use something like:

```
   layout = Layout()
   layout.image = "path/image.png"
   layout.save()
```

I tested and working in django 1.4, it might work also for an existing model.